# Adapters not output image(android)

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, sdk

Sorry for my english. I am using adapter, and I may be wrong somthing using it. I am trying to show image and textView as output. Textview is coming properly in the output, but image is not. Please help me, i try many many times fix it. Load image in `DownloadImageTask`. In `DownloadImageTask` i have class `ImageLoader`, i have used [this tutorial](http://www.technotalkative.com/android-load-images-from-web-and-caching/). I don't have any error, i have nothing(

```
ArrayList<News> ArrayListNews;
int Resourse;
Context context;
LayoutInflater vi;

public NewsAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<News> objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);

    ArrayListNews = objects;
    Resourse = resource;
    this.context = context;

    vi = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder;
    if(convertView == null) {
        convertView = vi.inflate(Resourse, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        holder.imageview = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imagenews);
        holder.nameNews = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.namenews);
        holder.dayNews = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.daynews);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    new DownloadImageTask(holder.imageview).execute(ArrayListNews.get(position).getImageNews());
    holder.nameNews.setText(ArrayListNews.get(position).getNameNews());
    holder.dayNews.setText(ArrayListNews.get(position).getDayNews());

    return convertView;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    public ImageView imageview;
    public TextView nameNews;
    public TextView dayNews;
}




//this is class set image
private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    ImageView bmImage;

    ImageLoader imgLoader;

    public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage) {
        this.bmImage = bmImage;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String urldisplay = urls[0];
        return urldisplay;

    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        imgLoader = new ImageLoader(context.getApplicationContext());
        imgLoader.DisplayImage(result, bmImage);

    } 
}
```

Comment: Do you require caching? Or you just want to load Images?

Comment: @Paritosh i want just load images. I wand display image in list view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will suggest you to use [Picasso library](http://square.github.io/picasso/). It is very easy to use. Just add dependency(Android Studio) or add .jar file into your library(in Eclipse).

```
Picasso.with(context).load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(imageView);
```

That's it. Now you will not need `AsyncTask` to download images.

Your `getView()` will be

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder;
    if(convertView == null) {
        convertView = vi.inflate(Resourse, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        holder.imageview = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imagenews);
        holder.nameNews = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.namenews);
        holder.dayNews = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.daynews);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    // I am not sure about return value of ArrayListNews.get(position).getImageNews(); 
    // It should be URL pointing to your image file
    Picasso.with(context).load(ArrayListNews.get(position).getImageNews()).into(holder.imageview);

    holder.nameNews.setText(ArrayListNews.get(position).getNameNews());
    holder.dayNews.setText(ArrayListNews.get(position).getDayNews());

    return convertView;
}
```